how fix the no module erro pyspark . it is installed but not work
import pyspark
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\Python file\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from pyspark.rdd import RDD, RDDBarrier
  File "E:\Python file\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 78, in <module>
    from pyspark.resource.requests import ExecutorResourceRequests, TaskResourceRequests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.resource'

How can resolve it   .

This question is similar to: No module named 'pyspark.resource' when running pyspark command. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
